# Python ´No matching distribution found for module´

Tags: python-3.x, module, pip

Got this:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shared'
```

so I did this:

```
pip install shared
```

but got this:

```
Collecting shared
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement shared (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for shared
```

Trying to run a script someone else wrote, doing it on a redhat cluster with python3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in or PyPI module name `shared`. 
It probably a user-defined module written by the author on his local system.

Try contacting the author of the code and clarify.

Comment: I did not even check GitHub